# Error "could not find node.js" in eclipse

Tags: python, node.js, eclipse

I am trying to learn json handling with Python in the eclipse IDE. But whenever I try to make a json file in eclipse this error comes

[image]

I have the latest version of eclipse and I need help to resolve this error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably using the JSON editor from [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) which indeed requires Node.js to provide JSON support beyond syntax highlighting. Node.js is required to run the JSON [language server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) like Java is required to run Eclipse.

You have the following options:

- Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) into your system
- Install embedded Node.js into Eclipse:

  1. Go to *Help > Install New Software...*
  2. Work with [`http://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/snapshots`](http://download.eclipse.org/wildwebdeveloper/snapshots)
  3. Choose *Node.js embedder from Wild Web Developer* and install it
- Use a different JSON editor that does not require Node.js:

  - [Eclipse Web Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-web-developer-tools-0)
  - [JSON Editor Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/json-editor-plugin)
  - [...](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/fileextension_json)

Comment: In my case I run *Help > Check for updates* and after updating all packages the error message about Missing Node.js disappeared.

Comment: @ino Yes, recent versions of Eclipse Wild Web Developer contains _Node.js embedder_. Check _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs and freezes the IDE (STS 4.7.2) when a dockerfile is opened and node.js is not installed or not in the path. As a solution, I removed all docker related plugins from STS and the problem is solved.